# Configuring linux gateway to forward packets

Tags: linux, routing, gateway

I have a windows box with a wireless card (ip 10.10.96.22) configured with a default gateway of 10.10.96.21/24 (this is my linux laptop's wireless ip). From the Windows box I can ping my linux laptop both through its wireless and wired IP's but I cannot ping any of the other machines on the wired subnet (10.96.18.0/24) to which my laptop is also connected. The linux configuration is as follows:

```
pp@think:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

pp@think:~$ ip route
default via 10.96.18.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.10.96.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.96.21  metric 2 
10.96.18.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.96.18.23  metric 1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 

pp@think:~$ sudo iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.96.22          10.96.18.0/24       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing here?

**Update**
I had neglected to check the routes coming back to the Windows box. Once that was setup everything worked.

Comment: You have to troubleshoot. Is the problem with the pings not getting to their destination or the ping replies not getting back? Does the gateway see the ping packets? Does it see the replies? (How do the machines on the wired subnet know where to send the reply packets? Is the gateway their default route?)

Comment: Yes, it was the reply route not being setup properly. Thank you for your help.